# Confidence interval on point biserial correlation coefficient in Ruby

Tags: ruby, statistics, correlation, confidence-interval

I'm using the [statsample](https://github.com/clbustos/statsample) gem to calculate point biserial correlation coefficient between a binary value (pass or fail a quiz) and a float value. I'm not sure how to calculate a confidence interval on these results.

I use the library as follows

```
correlation = Statsample::Bivariate.point_biserial(pass_fail_list, score_list)
```

[This paper](http://ncss.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/themes/ncss/pdf/Procedures/PASS/Confidence_Intervals_for_Point_Biserial_Correlation.pdf) contains the math, but it's a little over my head. Is there a library to do this? I don't think the math is actually too hard. Does anyone understand it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you don't get an good answer on SO, you may want to try http://stats.stackexchange.com/. The users there would be much better at explaining how to calculate confidence intervals. Also, you may want to specify in your question whether you are looking for a gem to do this for you, and/or how to do it with statsample.

Comment: This was answered well at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/154362/confidence-interval-on-point-biserial-correlation-coefficient